# Failed to fetch data from Heroku app. CORS error

Tags: express, heroku, redux, cors, fetch

I've been struggling with fetching data from my heroku app in Redux, and I'm running into a couple of CORS errors:

```
Failed to load https://app-name.herokuapp.com/users: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

and the second error

```
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I created the Heroku app from Express, and in my response code I have

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

My fetch function in Redux looks like

```
const url = "https://app-name.herokuapp.com/users";
return fetch(url, {
 method: 'GET',
 mode: 'cors',
 headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text' }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

On your cors settings you have http://localhost:3000 but your server is running on https://app-name.herokuapp.com.